# test return of an XML parse

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm trying to compare the value of an input text with the return of an Ajax request, but I don't know why the test doesn't work.
I'm working on Phonegap.
here's my code :

```
var contenu = $("#champ").val() ;
$("#envoi_search").click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://www.edumobile.org/blog/uploads/XML-parsing-data/Data.xml",
        data: "{}",
        cache: false,
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function(data) {
                            $(data).find("Book").each(function () {
                                if($(this).find("name").text() == contenu) {
                                    $("#result").append("<br> Titre : " + $(this).find("name").text());
                                    $("#result").append("<br> Auteur : " + $(this).find("address").text());
                                    $("#result").append("<br> Pays : " + $(this).find("country").text());
                                }
                            });
                            if($("#result").is(':empty')) {
                                $("#error").append("Désolé Aucun livre n\'a été trouvé") ;
                            }
                        }
    });
});
```

Do you have any idea about this problem ?
Thank you a lot :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can't access cross-domain assets with JavaScript.

Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/MVzgL/

This is the error output:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   http://www.edumobile.org/blog/uploads/XML-parsing-data/Data.xml.
>   Origin http://fiddle.jshell.net is not allowed by
>   Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

So if you are running this code on any domain other than `www.edumobile.org` then it won't be able to function. You can however setup a server-side proxy that grabs the remote content and then you call the proxy from your JS since it will be on the same domain. Setting-up this proxy is quite easy, you'd just request the information and then output it for JS (many server-side languages have native JSON encoding).